# Crashlytics with APKTool on build server

Tags: android, crashlytics, apktool

I´ve setup crashlytics for android using the suggested gradle method and while running in android studio things work fine. I get crash reports, statistics and everything just as expected (and looking great btw!).

The problem is when I want to use the same features in our release environment. We´re using APKtool on a build server to modify resources, package name and a few other things. Basically, we are producing a lot of release APKs all based on exactly the same code. When I run the produced release APKs nothing gets reported to crashlytics. From what I´ve understood it seems crashlytics communicates with the fabric API during the build process and since we are essentially creating a new APK (with a new package name) we probably need to do this manually somehow.

I´ve seen it mentioned in the ios beta distribution docs that you can run a script to submit created builds to the API so is there something similar available for Android, preferably without changing our whole build process?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Magnus. We need to detect an IDE build and a device or simulator run event to show the app in your dashboard per package name.

Reach out with your package names if you are running into issues and we can manually activate them. :)